Excel - Remove Contents of Row and Shift Rows Up
I have the following sheet that is essentially a batting order/lineup for baseball. I am attempting to remove a Player without having to make significant changes to the sheet to accommodate the removal.

For example, if I want to remove Player 8 from the lineup, I would clear the contents of A4:K4, then go through the pain staking process of hand jamming Player 1 into the #3 slot, Player 4 into the #4 slot, and so on. Copy and paste seems to work, but it messes up the formatting
What I would like to do is clear the contents of that #3 spot and move all other player's up one spot. I'm not entirely sure how to begin here, might sound like a job for a macro, but not sure?
As always, any help is appreciated.

This question belongs on [su], as it is a general Excel question and not a specific programming question.

To remove a player:
Select B4:K4 > Right-Click > Delete > Cells & Shift Up

To add a player:
Select B4:K4 > Right-Click > Insert > Cells & Shift Down

If formatting is a problem:

Convert the table to a proper table with Ctrl+T or via Insert > Table
Set the first column to a formula =ROW()-1
Delete the whole table row via Right-click > Delete > Table Rows. The first column will always recalculate.

